# FluentUI/React - Get key of dynamic checkbox list onChange

Tags: reactjs, typescript, checkbox, fluent-ui

Using React 17 with Fluent UI, I am trying to create a dynamic list of checkboxes. I have created the list of checkboxes, but I am struggling to get the `key` of each checkbox when they are selected, to update the state that is meant to be an array containing the keys of all the selected checkboxes.

Here is a Code Sandbox with a minimal reproducible example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-parm-1l3yyc?file=/src/App.tsx

I am open to suggestions that use a different property other than the key of the checkbox to store the values, but I am limited to using Fluent UI.

Here is the code I have used to generate the list of checkboxes (This is working). `profiles` is an array of objects that was created, the only properties that are used in this code is `name` and `token` which are both strings:

```
const getProfileCheckboxes = () => {
    var profiles = ProjectManager.getProfileList();
    const checkboxes = profiles.map(profile => 
        <Checkbox
            label={profile.name}
            defaultChecked={true}
            onChange={onChangeProfileCheckbox}
            key={profile.token}
        />
    );
    return checkboxes;
}
```

Below is where I am having issues, I have tried quite a few things for this function including all the answers to the related questions that I have found on Stack Overflow, but I have had no luck.

`selectedProfiles` defaults to an array containing all the profile tokens.

```
const onChangeProfileCheckbox = (ev: any) => {
    const value = "key of profile"; // Placeholder
    const checked = false; // Placeholder
    if (checked) {
        selectedProfiles.push(value);
    } else {
        setSelectedProfiles(prev => prev.filter(x => x !== value));
    }
}
```

Does anybody know how I can get the key and checked values in the onChange() function?

The `checked` values is less important since I can just check if the key is already contained in the state array, but I think it would be cleaner if I could get the value directly.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Could you provide minimal reproduction on codesandbox?

Comment: @DamianBusz Yea sure, I'll get started on that

Comment: @DamianBusz Thanks for the response, I have created a codesandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-parm-1l3yyc?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: I will be checking it, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get `checked` value directly from event that we have from onChange

The `key` property is used by React under the hood, and is not exposed to you. You'll want to use a custom property and pass that data in or as in your case, pass it directly into *onClick* function

here is how Checkbox should look:

```
 <Checkbox
    label={profile.name}
    defaultChecked={true}
    onChange={(ev) => onChangeProfileCheckbox(ev, profile.token)}
    key={profile.token}
  />
```

And here how your onChange function should look:

```
const onChangeProfileCheckbox = (ev: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>, token: string) => {
      const value = token;
      const checked = ev.target.checked;
      if (checked) {
          selectedProfiles.push(value);
       } else {
          setSelectedProfiles(prev => prev.filter(x => x !== value));
        }
    };
```

here is the link to [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/throbbing-bird-y09rk5?file=/src/App.tsx:310-624) with the result

Comment: The onChange callback can pass `ev` & `checked` so you could pass the `checked` as argument directly to it as well
`onChange={(ev, isChecked) => onChangeProfileCheckbox(ev, isChecked, profile.token)}`

Comment: This is something that I never heard of, awesome!